# Rails app with passenger and capistrano picking wrong gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I am trying to deploy rails app with Capistrano. App is deployed, bundle install is run in
    ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/pro/www/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet

But when I run the app, its using default gemset and not the gems from shared/bundled. I am getting following error

```
Message from application: <p>It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:</p>


Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

<pre>  /home/pro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@gemset/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize&#39;
```

I am not understanding the problem here. MY deploy.rb file has:

```
set :application, 'rails_a[['
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:user/app.git'
# set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.3.1@gemset'
```

set :stages, %w(production)
   set :deploy_to, '/home/pro/www'

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your configuration. Since rvm sets the `$GEM_HOME` env variable according to the ruby version, and bundler defaults it's path(i.e. `BUNDLE_PATH`) to `$GEM_HOME` (in development at least). You can override this in bundler config.

Inside your application directory.

```
bundle config --local path /home/pro/www/shared/bundle
```

The `local` flag will keep the changes specific to your Application, you should also remove `.bundle` from your `.gitignore` to push your bundle configs to your deployment server.

Have a look at the bundle config [documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html).

[This](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/09/configuring-bundler-using-bundle-config.html) is also a nice blog post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Capistrano and RVM

[ruby]
$:.unshift(File.expand_path(‘./lib’, ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, ‘ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3.2′
set :rvm_type, :user
[/ruby]
```

Here @rails3.2 is gemset. when capistrano will invoke bundle install it will take this gemset. so You need to set rvm_ruby_string